# openfiledialog give error on cancel button , Visual Basic & i am suing this code

Tags: vb.net

```
ofd.ShowDialog()
If ofd.FileName = Nothing Then

ElseIf ofd.FileName = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim fl As String
    fl = ofd.FileName
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(fl)
    TextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
    sr.Close()
End If
```

Comment: I am suing my code too!

Comment: Please add also the text of the error message (IE the exception)

Comment: Please try to format your code properly, and do include some kind of explanation in your question. The error message is a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check what button the user has pressed by checking the return value of `ShowDialog()`. Checking for `OK` *(returned when you actually select a file)* should fix your problem getting errors when you press Cancel.

```
If ofd.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim fl As String
    fl = ofd.FileName

    Dim sr As New StreamReader(fl)
    TextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
    sr.Close()
End If
```